# How to compute standard deviation of the amounts depending on the accounts and week intervals?

Tags: r, standard-deviation

This is my transaction data. (I will skip some of the rows.)

```
df <- df %>% arrange(from_id, date_trx)

from_id       to_id       date_trx       amount       week 
<fctr>        <fctr>      <date>         <dbl>        <dbl>
...           ...         ...            ...          ...
5370          6979        2006-11-30     25653.0      79
5370          7564        2007-01-13     9658.0       85
5370          8744        2007-04-14     34430.0      98
5370          7318        2007-06-05     21495.0      106
5370          8433        2007-06-22     200.0        108
5370          7122        2007-07-22     5300.0       112
5370          8566        2007-08-21     7500.0       117
5370          6728        2007-08-31     171.6        118
5370          9689        2007-08-31     14.6         118
5370          8342        2007-09-05     2452.0       119
```

I want to compute standard deviation of the amounts for each `from_id`s at each `week`.
I tried:

`week_sd <- aggregate(amount ~ from_id+ week, df, sd) %>% arrange(from_id, date_trx)`
It produced this result

```
from_id    week       week_sd
<fctr>     <dbl>       <dbl>
...        ...        ...
5370       79         NA        
5370       85         NA        
5370       98         NA        
5370       106        NA        
5370       108        NA        
5370       112        NA        
5370       117        NA        
5370       118        111.015765        
5370       119        NA        
5370       121        NA
```

If we look at the data above, there are two transactions that 5370 made in 118th week, with the amounts 171.6 and 14.6. And, the standard deviation for 5370 in 118th week computed as 111.015765 whereas it should be 78.5. Why is it like this? Also why are others NA instead of 0?

Comment: check `sd(c(171.6,14.6))`

Comment: try `aggregate(amount ~ from_id+ week, df, FUN=sd , na.rm = T) `

Comment: oh, okay I guess it has sth to do with the definition of standard deviation @RonakShah